# SpriteKit — SwiftUI SpriteView, animation lag on keyboard appear/disappear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteView to display a SpriteKit scene in SwiftUI. I have a textfield in the EditObject SwiftUI struct, and when the keyboard appears / disappears, the keyboard animation is laggy / jittery.

I suspect this is due to the SpriteView. The SpriteView (and everything else) is avoiding the keyboard. I have no idea why I can't prevent this. I've tried:

```swift
.ignoresSafeArea()
.ignoresSafeArea([.container, .keyboard])
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
.ignoresSafeArea(.container)
```

on all elements here, e.g:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GameViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            SpriteView(scene: viewModel.scene)
                .ignoresSafeArea([.container, .keyboard])
            
            if viewModel.showMenu {
                EditObject(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .ignoresSafeArea([.container, .keyboard])
            }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea([.container, .keyboard])
    }
}
```

Ideally I just want the SpriteView to not avoid the keyboard (to stay fixed in place at al times). But I can't even get the other parts to not avoid, either.

Alternatively is there a way to avoid the keyboard animation lag with SpriteView?